# Erro ao Editar ou Excluir itens pelo Delphi 10.1 depois de Atualizar o Firebird

Tags: delphi-10

Oi, gente estou passando por um problema não estou conseguindo excluir ou Editar nada do banco de dados pelo sistema criado pelo Delphi 10.1. 
Isso começou a ocorrer logo a pois eu migrar do Firebird 2.1 para o Firebird 2.5 pelo menos é a última mudança mais significativa que eu fiz depois de migrar o sistema para o Delphi 10.1. 
Não mudei nada do código original com relação a `insert`, `edit` e `Delet`.

Logo que abro a tela de cadastro de usuários eu Clico no botão editar a tabela entra em modo de edição depois que faço as mudanças e clico no botão salvar ele passa pelo comando `post` normalmente mais não salva o mesmo ocorre com excluir.

Comment: Eu vou tentar reinstalar o Firebird hoje para ver se volta ao normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de Tanto tentar verifiquei que tinha que atualizar os `Fields` de cada tabela então apaguei cada `field` de cada Tabla e coloquei um novo `FDConnection` as funções de atualizar e excluir voltaram a funcionar.